# Attach/Embed blob to PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is it possible to attach a blob (store in database) to a PDF file using the JAvA iText library or any other library ?

Comment: Attach as what? As a generic file attachment? Yes, trivially.

Comment: Thxx its worked

Comment: How did it work? You might want to add your solution as an answer here and accept it. This will help all the other users having the same problem...